# Why is the internal hard drive not available when attempting to install Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.10 from a USB drive?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, hard-drive, usb-installation

When I attempt to install either Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.10 from a USB flash drive to a Dell Latitude 5500 PC with Windows 10, only the USB drive appears on the "Allocate Drive Space" screen (as sda); the internal hard drive (SSD) is not visible. In other words, I can only install Ubuntu to the USB flash drive; the hard drive is not an option. How can I make the hard drive visible so that I can install to it?

Comment: What is installed already in the SSD? If it is Windows, have you shut down Windows completely?

Comment: Yes, Windows fast startup was already disabled. The problem was the SSD was set as RAID instead of AHCI. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change UEFI/BIOS from SATA to AHCI mode:

1. In Windows, run MSCONFIG (as administrator)
2. Enable Safe Boot (minimal)
3. Restart
4. At DELL boot up screen, press F2 to enter UEFI/BIOS setup.
5. Select SATA Operation from System Confirmation and change to AHCI
6. When asked “Are you sure you would like to continue?”, select Yes
7. Boot in safe mode (happens automatically because of Step 2)
8. Run MSCONFIG (as administrator) and disable Safe
   Boot.
9. Restart Windows

Then, restart and boot from Ubuntu bootable USB to install Ubuntu.

See the following pages for additional information:

- https://www.tenforums.com/customization/104898-switch-raid-ahci.html
- https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci
- https://mashtips.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-windows10/
- https://www.pcsuggest.com/dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu-uefi/
- https://partition.toolpie.com/
- https://www.convertunits.com/from/GB/to/MB

Comment: Thank you for documenting the steps!